# What's this art-style?

Tags: style-identification

[image: My art style]

Hiya, I was browsing google looking for what my art style is called, and I came across this image, which I think describes my art style perfectly. So, I have to ask, what is the name of this art style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Modern Cartoon Art Style

These are simple drawings that are common these days in TV caricatures, like The Simpsons, Avatar (not the blue guys), and those other types.